# Renaming items in an array of objects in Javascript React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects that is similar to the one below.  I want map over the array and change the keys.  So, for example "job_id" would become "id".  "job_title" would become name ect.  How can I do this with a large array(thousands of items)?

```
Array of objects [
  {
    "job_id": "linkedin_appcast_cpce6c19a8ce6c19a8c-10440_2693788743",
    "job_title": ".NET Developer",
    "location": "Saint Louis, MO, USA",
    "num_days_since_posted": "2021-08-29T05:06:56Z",
    "location_geo_point": {
      "lat": "38.6529545",
      "lon": "-90.24111656024635"
    }
  }
    {
    "job_id": "linkedin_appcast_cpce6c19a8ce6c19a8c-10440_2693788743",
    "job_title": ".NET Developer",
    "location": "Saint Louis, MO, USA",
    "num_days_since_posted": "2021-08-29T05:06:56Z",
    "location_geo_point": {
      "lat": "38.6529545",
      "lon": "-90.24111656024635"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This really should be done server side

Answer (score 2):

You could create an object with each `key` being the key that needs to be changed, and each `value` being the `newKey` that will take it's place.

```js
const replace = {
  job_id: 'id',
  job_title: 'name',
};
```

Then in each iteration of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), go through each key in `replace` using a  [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and check for keys that need replacing.

```js
data.map((object) => {
  for (const key in replace) {
    if (object[key]) {
      object[replace[key]] = object[key];
      delete object[key];
    }
  }
  return object;
});
```

**Full code:**

```js
const data = [ { job_id: 'linkedin_appcast_cpce6c19a8ce6c19a8c-10440_2693788743', job_title: '.NET Developer', location: 'Saint Louis, MO, USA', num_days_since_posted: '2021-08-29T05:06:56Z', location_geo_point: { lat: '38.6529545', lon: '-90.24111656024635', }, }, { job_id: 'linkedin_appcast_cpce6c19a8ce6c19a8c-10440_2693788743', job_title: '.NET Developer', location: 'Saint Louis, MO, USA', num_days_since_posted: '2021-08-29T05:06:56Z', location_geo_point: { lat: '38.6529545', lon: '-90.24111656024635', }, }, ];

const replace = {
  job_id: 'id',
  job_title: 'name',
};

let res = data.map((object) => {
  for (const key in replace) {
    if (object[key]) {
      object[replace[key]] = object[key];
      delete object[key];
    }
  }
  return object;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to generate a list of all the keys from a given object, check if it starts with "job_" or whichever piece you're trying to remove, and make a new object with updated versions of the object's data. See demo code below or example of this code in action in the repl at the bottom.

```
const replaceKeys = (obj) => {
  const allKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  const newObj = {};
  allKeys.forEach((key) => {
    if (key.slice(0, 4) === 'job_') {
      newObj[key.slice(4)] = obj[key];
    } else {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  })
  return newObj;
};
```

[Example demo of this in a repl I spun up here.](https://replit.com/@saintjustin/FabulousDutifulGenericsoftware)